# How to disable the automatic sorting of items alphabetically in Choices.js?

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have the following array:

```
options = [
  "Asset Management & Investment Funds",
  "Financial Institutions",
  "Life Sciences",
  "TMT",
  "Other"
]
```

[Choices.js](https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices) by default sorts it alphabetically, and `Other` ends up before `TMT` which is jarring for the user.

```
const $projectDropdown = new Choices($this[0], {
  placeholder: true,
  placeholderValue: 'Select a project'
})
```

I tried look into the `sortFilter` function, but it only specifies the method of sorting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you need the property `shouldSort`. The [readme](https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices/blob/master/README.md) has details.

```
const $projectDropdown = new Choices($this[0], {
  placeholder: true,
  placeholderValue: 'Select a project'
  shouldSort: false,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Default sorting is true but you can pass another property shouldSort.

```
const $projectDropdown = new Choices($this[0], {
  placeholder: true,
  placeholderValue: 'Select a project',
  shouldSort: false
})
```